# 'ConnectionAborted Error' on Uploading new Appbundle to Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to upload a new appbundle. I can register the appbundle and it goes through fine, but when I try to upload the appbundle I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))
```

Is it s server side error? How can I get around it?

Comment: Could you share which API did you call as well as your request payload? If that is not proper posting here publicly, you can reach out via the email `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com`. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In turned out that the issue was I was adding the Forge Auth header to the call and I guess it was causing the failure. Wish the error message was more helpful.

Comment: This tripped me up too... Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

At this point you are talking to Amazon AWS S3 directly. None of our code is in the picture. It could be a temporary glitch in S3 (and then your should simply retry). Or it is possible that your request is malformed. See https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/appbundles-POST/

Comment: We have tried calling this method multiple times over the past 3 days from different machines. it keeps failing. Is there a way to look at the amazon logs? Or see if that endpoint is failing at a high rate?

Comment: @EhsanBarekati - how big is your bundle size, I'm suspecting s3 is emitting error for bigger file size, as Albert says DA has not yet entered yet. Create a s3 bucket of your own, try uploading the same bundle.zip see if you are succeeding ? Forge DA rate limit for app bundles is 100 MB (compressed) , 500 MB (uncompressed)